# Mongoose: display results of find() as a table

Tags: mongoose

I'm looking for a very simple example of how to take the output of this code and turn it into HTML that I can display through Jade.

```
var server1 = Server.find({},
            function(err, docs) {
            if (!err){ 
               console.log(docs);
                      }
            else { throw err;}
            }
    );
 res.render('servers', { title: 'verify', results: server1});
}
```

My jade template contains this:

```
table
  each result in results
    tr
      td= result.name
      td= result.os
```

But, I am getting this error: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

If i try just 'result' i get what looks like a dump of MongoDB settings.

My console.log looks like this when I load the page, so I know I am pulling dummy data from the DB but I can't get it to display in Jade:

{ osVersion: 'gbgbgb',
    os: 'bgbgbgb',
    name: 'bgbgbgbgb',
    _id: 52e1574c10abec5571b99be2,
    __v: 0,
    licenses: [],
    createdOn: Thu Jan 23 2014 12:54:20 GMT-0500 (EST) },
  { osVersion: 'h',
    os: 'h',
    name: 'h',
    _id: 52e15e5510abec5571b99be3,
    __v: 0,
    licenses: [],
    createdOn: Thu Jan 23 2014 13:24:21 GMT-0500 (EST) }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `res.render` from inside the callback function.

```
var server1 = Server.find({},
        function(err, docs) {
        if (!err){ 
            res.render('servers', { title: 'verify', results: docs });
                  }
        else { throw err;}
        }

);
```

The return value of `Server.find()` is not the result of the query, the result of the query is passed to the callback function.

The Mongoose documentation page on queries (http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) has a lot of good examples of the `find()` function.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The mongoosejs.com docs seem to be aimed at someone who has a good deal of experience with JavaScript. That unfortunately is not me.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working fairly well

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  Server.find({},
    function(err, docs) {
      if (!err){ 
          res.render('servers', { title: 'verify', results: docs});
      }
      else { throw err;}
    }
  );
}
```

and then my Jade file looks like this:

```
  table
    each result in results
      tr
        td #{result.name}
        td #{result.os}
        td #{result.createdOn}
```